# Why the image in image view is blurry?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to take launch camera using the app I built, somehow during the image processing, the image turns out to be very blur.

Is there anyway I can get a clear images?

```
    [Activity(Label = "LaunchCamera")]
public class LaunchCamera : Activity
{

    ImageView imageView;
    private const int requestCode = 20;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Camera);
        // Create your application here

        var mBtnCamera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
        imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.photoView);



        mBtnCamera.Click += MBtnCamera_ClickAsync;
    }

    private void MBtnCamera_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Intent cameraFire = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);




        StartActivityForResult(cameraFire,requestCode)

    }

   protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap); 



    }
}
```

Help it out.

Prompt reply is appreciated.

Comment: here one thing is possible that your imageView size is big and u r trying small image to set on imageView  try with different camera or try to make imageView small.

Answer (score 2):

Getting Image from Camera in Android is pretty simple, however it gets pretty tricky if you need to get full quality image from the camera. When you launch intent with action image capture ,what you basically get is just the thumbnail. For getting the high quality full size photo, you need to save the high quality photo in the phone storage or external storage and then get that photo using Uri. Without saving the photo, you cannot get a high quality photo from the camera.
Instead of using default directory to store picture create your own directory to store images.

```
  private void CreateDirectoryForPictures ()
    {
        App._dir = new File (
            Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (
                Environment.DirectoryPictures), "CameraAppDemo");
        if (!App._dir.Exists ())
        {
            App._dir.Mkdirs( );
        }
    }
```

**Pass that Uri to the camera intent**

```
private void TakeAPicture (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    App._file = new File (App._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
    intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile (App._file));
    StartActivityForResult (intent, 0);
}
```